# How to pass objects to aws-amplify-vue SignUp?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using [AWS-amplify amplify Authentication Components](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/vue_guide#authentication-components) in my Vue app.

This allows me to have an easy way to register and authenticate users with amazon cognito. Unfortunatly, I am not able to change the SignUp Component, to display an additional field and remove the phone_number as mandatory field.

Any help is welcome!
Best Regards

Comment: Just to be clear, the ideal way would to pass that to the <amplify-authenticator></amplify-authenticator>. Therefore I only would have one element :)

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it. Just in case someone finds this question.

```html
<amplify-authenticator :authConfig='authConfig'></amplify-authenticator>
```

```js
data() {
    return {
        authConfig: {
            signUpConfig: {
                header: 'Sign up for an account',
                hiddenDefaults: ['phone_number', 'username'],
                signUpFields: [
                    {
                        label: 'Email',
                        key: 'email',
                        type: 'string',
                        required: true,
                        displayOrder: 0
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Password',
                        key: 'password',
                        type: 'password',
                        required: true,
                        displayOrder: 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            confirmSignUpConfig: {
                header: 'Please enter the code sent to your email'
            },
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to bind to v-bind:authOptions the documentation makes reference to v-bind:authConfig which is wrong.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: <amplify-authenticator v-bind:authOptions="authOptions"></amplify-authenticator>
with:
authOptions = {
      phone_number:false,
    }
in the App.vue
or 
authOptions : {
      phone_number:false,
    }
as part of 
Amplify.configure({ in aws-exports.js has not solved the issue - unfortunatly.

Comment: sure, maybe the complete solution will help you. you should have <amplify-authenticator v-bind:authOptions="authOptions"></amplify-authenticator> on the template section. Now on the data section you should refers to the authOptions : { signUpConfig: { signUpFields: [{
                                label: 'Name',
                                key: 'name',
                                required: true,
                                displayOrder:   1,
                                type:   'string'
                            }]}};

Comment: @MichelRoger, what makes you say `authConfig` is 'wrong'?

I am using `aws-amplify-vue@^0.2.6-beta.1` and binding to `authConfig` is indeed the correct thing to do and works as intended.

This can be verified by looking at the `props` of the `amplify-authenticator` component in the source code at https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/efc081f3d69141528f386807996c1899e97f8b5f/packages/aws-amplify-vue/src/components/authenticator/Authenticator.vue#L32